# What is the intuition behind uniform and non uniform patterns in LBP?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

In uniform LBP (local binary pattern) mapping there is a separate output label for each uniform pattern and all the non-uniform patterns are assigned to a single label.what is the intuition behind this notion, i need your help.

Comment: This is well explained in the Wiki page for [LBP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns). Check the last paragraph of the **Concept** section.

Comment: @dhanushka thanks, but what mean: "all the non-uniform patterns are assigned to a single label"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we use 4 sampling points (in red) on a circle of radius R as shown in the image below as our LBP.

[image]

So, we'll get 16 (= 2^4) different patterns (or labels). A pattern is uniform if it has at most two 1->0 or 0->1 transitions when traversed **circularly**. We'll assign a unique label for each uniform pattern, and assign all non-uniform patterns the same label as shown below.

```
pattern circular    uniform   label
        transitions     
0000       0         yes      lbl0
0001       2         yes      lbl1
0010       2         yes      lbl2
0011       2         yes      lbl3
0100       2         yes      lbl4
0101       4         no       lbl5     ***
0110       2         yes      lbl6
0111       2         yes      lbl7
1000       2         yes      lbl8
1001       2         yes      lbl9
1010       4         no       lbl5     ***
1011       2         yes      lblA
1100       2         yes      lblB
1101       2         yes      lblC
1110       2         yes      lblD
1111       0         yes      lblE
```

Initially we had 16 labels, meaning we had 16 bins in the histogram, or 16 features in the feature vector. With the introduction of uniform pattern concept, now we have only 15 labels, or 15 bins in the histogram, or 15 features in the feature vector (which is not a significant improvement over the original. But for 8 sampling points, this will be initially 256 and only 59 with uniform patterns).

Concept of uniform patterns

- greatly reduces the size of the feature vector when it comes to higher number of sampling points
- experiments have shown that uniform patterns occur more frequently in texture images than non-uniform patterns (extract form  [[link]](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Local_Binary_Patterns): "*Ojala et al. (2002) noticed in their experiments with texture images that uniform patterns account for a little less than 90% of all patterns when using the (8,1) neighborhood and for around 70% in the (16,2) neighborhood.*").

Therefore uniform patterns make using LBP computationally more efficient without compromising its accuracy.

But if your particular application of LBP doesn't suggest that uniform patterns are frequent in your dataset, you may not get accurate results by using uniform patterns.

Comment: thank you very much ,but how do uniform pattern can be  rotation  invariant although the each uniform pattern assigned to unique label, i wish  help me thanks.

Comment: @Amine : i think it might be helpful to read this paper 'Gray Scale and Rotation Invariant Texture Classification with Local Binary Patterns' which you can download from [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.96.5229&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Specifically section 2.3.